# How to cache images using dynamic image URIs?

Tags: android, image, caching, universal-image-loader

How can I setup the [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load dynamic image URIs?

For instance:

Both URIs must be representing the same remote image `image.jpg`:

- https://sample.com/image.jpg?querystring=1
- https://sample.com/image.jpg?querystring=2
- and so on...

Reference:

> Sometime, you may not want to use the image URL as cache key because
> part of the URL is dynamic (i.e.: for access control purpose)

[SDWebImage - Using cache key filter](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-cache-key-filter)

I am using the SDWebImage inside my iOS application and I really need a similar feature to be able to use the UIL inside its Android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this memory cache decorator:

```
public class CustomMemoryCache implements MemoryCacheAware<String, Bitmap> {

    private final MemoryCacheAware<String, Bitmap> cache;

    public CustomMemoryCache(MemoryCacheAware<String, Bitmap> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean put(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return cache.put(cleanKey(key), value);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap get(String key) {
        return cache.get(cleanKey(key));
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(String key) {
        cache.remove(cleanKey(key));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> keys() {
        return cache.keys();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }

    private String cleanKey(String key) {
        return key.substring(0, key.lastIndexOf("?")) + 
                 key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("_")); 
            // original cache key is like "[imageUri]_[width]x[height]"
    }
}
```

Then wrap any ready memory cache implementation and set it into the configuration.
For example:

```
LruMemoryCache memoryCache = new LruMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize);
CustomMemoryCache memoryCacheDecorator = new CustomMemoryCache(memoryCache);

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    ...
    .memoryCache(memoryCacheDecorator)
    ...
    .build();
```